# jQuery Callback Scope

Tags: jquery, scope, callback

Lets say I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.checkbox').change(function()
   {
      $('.hidden').slideUp('slow', function()
      {
         alert(checkbox value);
      }
   }
}
```

How do I access the checkboxes value? $(this) doesn't work as you're now in the .hidden element?

Answer (score 6):

You could capture the value in the outer function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {
        var $checkbox = $(this);
        $('.hidden').slideUp('slow', function() {
            alert($checkbox.val());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that was easier than I expected... How would I then go about converting $checkbox to a jQuery object so I can get access to .attr() ?

Comment: @Matt, I've updated my sample to capture the jQuery element instead of the native one.